# LINQ to SQL generates negative conditions in WHERE clause

Tags: linq-to-sql

I am using LINQ to SQL to retrieve data, using boolean conditions (BIT columns in SQL).  My LINQ query looks something like this:

```
var query = from r in db.Requests
            select r;
query = query.Where(r => r.Completed == someBooleanVal);
query = query.Where(r => r.Cancelled == someOtherBool);
return query.ToList();
```

The 'Where()' gets applied in a different method, that's why I'm putting it in separately.

When the boolean values are given as false, the generated SQL looks something like this:

```
SELECT [t0].[col1], [t0].[col2], [t0].[col3], [t0].[etc]
FROM [dbo].[Requests] AS [t0]
WHERE (NOT(([t0].[Cancelled]) = 1) AND (NOT(([t0].[Completed]) = 1)
```

in stead of what I would use:

```
WHERE [t0].[Cancelled] = 0 AND [t0].[Completed] = 0
```

This runs very, very slowly.  I strongly suspect that it is because of the negative conditions on the boolean values it generated (all the selected columns are covered by an index, and the two columns in the where clause have a separate index on them).

Why is it generating negative conditions?  How can I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried executing the 'cleaned up' (i.e. non-negative-conditions) SQL to see how this performs compared to the Linq generated SQL?

Comment: Are the bit fields maybe nullable?

Comment: I have tried it with the non-negative conditions.  In a test I did: With non-negative conditions the query takes less than a second.  With the generated query, it takes more than 3 seconds.

Comment: No, the fields are not nullable.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this yet? We're facing the same problem, even though we're using the same construction as 1234567890 But it still generates the `NOT`-SQL.

Comment: No, unfortunately not. If I remember correctly we eventually replaced it with a manual (optimized) SQL query using the DataContext's Execute method.

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = 
    from r in db.Requests.Where(r => r.Completed == someBooleanVal && r.Cancelled == someOtherBool)
    select r;

    return query.ToList();
```

Hope it can help you and have a nice day.